# empire db code-gen double parse failure in reading "0.-127" from table meta data

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, code-generation

I'm trying to reverse engineer using empire db code-gen on my project tables in Oracle.

For a primary key column (ID), the meta-data returned has invalid values ( `COLUMN_SIZE` is `0` and for field `DECIMAL_DIGITS` is `-127` ), which is the cause of Exception : `For input string: "0.-127"`

Can anyone enligthen me on why `DECIMAL_DIGITS` is -127.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.-127"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at org.apache.empire.db.codegen.CodeGenParser.addColumn(CodeGenParser.java:368)
    at org.apache.empire.db.codegen.CodeGenParser.populateTable(CodeGenParser.java:300)
    at org.apache.empire.db.codegen.CodeGenParser.populateDatabase(CodeGenParser.java:168)
    at org.apache.empire.db.codegen.CodeGenParser.loadDbModel(CodeGenParser.java:96)
    at org.apache.empire.db.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.java:57)
    at org.apache.empire.db.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.java:72)
    at org.apache.empire.db.codegen.CodeGenerator.main(CodeGenerator.java:45)
```

I invoke the CodeGenerator using `mvn generate-sources`

PS: I've tried both ojdbc6 and ojdbc14 jars, it didn't work.

Comment: Please add `empire-db` as a tag, I can't

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be related to the issue reported here: [DatabaseMetaData.getColumns() returns unexpected values in COLUMN_SIZE and DECIMAL_DIGITS for INTEGER columns](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3677876) (the -127 is coming from "int decimalDig = rs.getInt("DECIMAL_DIGITS");")

And running the JVM with the option "-Doracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true" seems to fix it. Could you try?

Comment: Tried `mvn generate-sources -Doracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true` didn't work, neither did `MAVEN_OPTS="-Doracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=true"` and then mvn `generate-sources`, let me know if I'm doing something wrong in setting JVM options.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this is a bug in Oracle JDBC:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3677876

As workaround you could change line 368 in CodeGenParser.java if rs.getInt("DECIMAL_DIGITS") is -127.